# Variable substitution in bash

Tags: bash

I've recently discovered `notify-send`, which opens up a notification window, so I can do things like:

```
compile && notify-send "Done!" || notify-send "Failed"
```

This made me thing that maybe I want to create a variable:

```
export NS="&& notify-send \"Done!\" || notify-send \"Failed\""
```

and then I could easily add it to many command lines for which I want notifications:

```
compile $NS
send-big-file $NS
start-a-heavy-job $NS
```

etc. But this obviously doesn't work as it is, and I can't seem to be able to come up with the right combination of variable substitutions to make it work... any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write a function that takes the command as an argument (untested):

```
ns() {
    "$@" && notify-send Done || notify-send Failed
}

ns compile
...
```